# 24 hrs format is not returning correct value in MS-edge

Tags: javascript, typescript, microsoft-edge

```js
const gmtDate = new Date("2023-11-03T18:49:27.652173+00:00"); // Date in GMT

const localTimeZone = "Asia/Kolkata"; // Replace with your desired time zone

const options = {
  weekday: 'short',
  year: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  hour12: false,
  timeZoneName: 'short',
  timeZone: localTimeZone,

};

const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language, options);
const localDateStr = dateFormatter.format(gmtDate);

console.log(localDateStr);
```

Current output -> "Sat, 4 Nov, 2023, 24:19 IST"

Expected output -> ""Sat, 4 Nov, 2023, 00:19 IST"

Objective -> I was trying to get a 24hrs local time from 24hrs format UTC time.

TS link -> [TS example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gWygEQIZQKYwLwzBgdxjUwAoAiAJgAZKBmAWgEYmHq6AVJgDgC4AWAJy9KAdgB0ANgCslJqLoBqatV4ryASgDcMAPS7i6LAEswMAOIBZDgCgboSLAA2IYKicdjCDAC1wWXHIAQQhjVF0AaRAnAGt0VHIdfRgAJQwABydUYCwCYygACxgATxAAVwAnGAATDFCKjGqYKC8sAC9-OwdoGBB0lvAIHBgAbxsYCZgCDAwY6tRi3hgAcggCkAqoZYAaccnijFQKpeWwMu8K42AdvYn5xZWzi6ubyZgEcEKTtY2t3bf1pUTpQGNVjHB8q9JghTGVMMDQeDIf9JoCKkxKEsAGbuCAYFETFrePz4AByqG833WmxuRN8-iWLjcHlaJPxdgAvlouoNYPNMAAxDYIdCYKq4fBEACSYCgTnEJAwnm8QoqIqgpDAqAAbuD0BtxFkwHAyqg4Pjev1jINtPZeTAme5FQBlKDimpGVXqsXiLHC9CkRAoIy2u2QaIYQ0gOCkR1OF1u7RAA)

Details
Browser -> MS-edge

[image]

Can somebody please help me out !

It is working everywhere else except MS-edge

Comment: Getting **Sat, 4 Nov 2023, 00:19 GMT+5:30**  as the output, isn't that you are expecting that.

Comment: Yes that is what was expected MS-edge is returning it wrong

Comment: I have added more details in the question can you please relook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the hour12 options, instead use hourCycle option. This will fix the bug on all browsers.

```js
const gmtDate = new Date("2023-11-03T18:49:27.652173+00:00"); // Date in GMT
const localTimeZone = "Asia/Kolkata"; // Replace with your desired time zone

const options = {
  weekday: 'short',
  year: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  hourCycle: 'h23',
  timeZoneName: 'short',
  timeZone: localTimeZone,
};

const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.language, options);
const localDateStr = dateFormatter.format(gmtDate);

console.log(localDateStr);
```

Comment: Upvote.  Also, when hourCycle is omitted it defaults to using the time format of the specified language.  So if the language is 'en-US' the time is 24:19 whereas 'en-UK' outputs '00:24'.

Comment: It works but now ts is complaining

Type '{ hourCycle: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'hourCycle' does not exist in type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'.

Comment: There is a work around to make options as any but is there any better to do it?

@Krzysztof Krzeszewski

Comment: Yes better way is en-UK but unfortunately I cannot do that since I need IST, PST etc... not in +5:30 etc....

If I use "en-UK" IST changes to +5:30 same goes for PST